# Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError pthread_create at socket.io

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am using **`io.socket.client`** in my android application. Sometimes I am getting "`Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed:`" error on my application. I was not able to reproduce this issue. I got the following log from the Fabric Crash report,

Here is the log,

```
       Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.create(PollingXHR.java:232)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR.doPoll(PollingXHR.java:129)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.poll(Polling.java:95)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.doOpen(Polling.java:35)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:82)
       at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:55)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.open(Transport.java:77)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$2.run(Socket.java:248)
       at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:55)
       at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.open(Socket.java:226)
       at io.socket.client.Manager$1.run(Manager.java:330)
       at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:55)
       at io.socket.client.Manager.open(Manager.java:250)
       at io.socket.client.Manager$11$1.run(Manager.java:560)
       at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Difficult to say why this happens just by looking on the error log and not having the code. 
You shoul check if you have ongoing / not closing loops or statements in your code and try using an avm with increased memory.
Please report if this solves your problem.

Comment: @JohannesGriebenow let me check

Answer (score -2):

According to the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html):

> OutOfMemoryError is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot
>   allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory
>   could be made available by the garbage collector. OutOfMemoryError
>   objects may be constructed by the virtual machine as if suppression
>   were disabled and/or the stack trace was not writable.

The application attempts to add more data into the heap space area, but there is not enough room for it.

Make sure there is no memory leak. If not then you have to increase you maximum heap memory size.

Comment: You only described what an OOME exception is, this doesn't explain in depth how it can be solved

Comment: Explain me why do you expect an in depth analysis without submitting any code?

Comment: You can still add something on the `largeHeap` tag in the manifest, avoid allocating more instances than you need, etc

Comment: From the looks of things, you're not an Android developer. That's why its worth mentioning that the OOME's are different. you can't *just* allocate more heap and say your app needs 1.5 gigs, the memory is allocated automatically but if too much is used by the app at once, you'll get an OOME from that because the OS doesn't allocate more memory the the app because it consumes it too quick

Comment: If you are an actual developer you should have heard about the root cause of an Exception. The route cause of OOME in Java is a memory leak or a low heap size allocation. If you want a deeper analysis then update your question with more details.

Comment: The root of an OOME is not having enough memory. Why that is is either memory leaks, allocating too many for an instance large images or something else that reduces the available memory until you do something that pushes it over the edge into missing memory.

Comment: Oh, and you apparently didn't notice but I'm not OP of the question

Comment: So what? Please rephrase you comment "The root of an OOME...". It is incomprehensible.

Comment: You wrote `not incomprehensible` meaning there is not a problem understanding it. So why rephase if there isn't a problem?

Comment: Correct you comment for the sake of the conversation flow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157649/discussion-between-zoe-and-anastasios-vlasopoulos).